# Android Support Design library component not added properly to Xamarin Android Project

Tags: xamarin.android, android-support-design, xamarin-component

I've started learning Xamarin for Android in visual studio, few days back. I'm a noob to this.

I need to build a navigation drawer, for which I need Android support v7 component and Android Support Design Component.

I added both of these from Component store.

But the design component shows 'Incomplete' in brackets in components list, also I'm unable to use it's widgets in project.

It looks like it isn't actually added to my project.

Below are the screenshots for this component.

**1) Incomplete status**

[image]

**2) Package reference error, when double clicked on Support design component**

[image]

Looking forward to response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this resolved.

What I did is, I removed the component for Android Support Design, and searched for the same in nuGet packages.

Downloaded it from there, and it is now correctly referenced by my project.

Thanks anyways.